# Knowledge sidebar panel on case - which settings controls the fields to be displayed?

Tags: knowledge, service-cloud-console

So I have added the knowledge panel sidebar into case according to this article - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/set-up-salesforce-knowledge/manage-cases-using-articles. But I don't know how to set which fields to be displayed for knowledge in this sidebar.

Personally I do feel like this should be something like a listview or search bar. But I can't seem to find the document related to this. Which setting should this one be?

Comment: what fields do you see on the component when you drag it by default? I'm also struggling to find where to change this and wondering if it is not customizable.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of which fields you are trying to alter?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I have seen the article title, number, publish status, and last modified date